# NullPointerException in Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I have a JFrame with JTextFields that take input from a user to add to an array.

Here is the ActionListener for it

```
class ButtonHandlerSub implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){if(ae.getSource() == add2){
            //add new student here
            Student temp = new Student(Integer.parseInt(tId.getText()),tName.getText(),tCourse.getText(),
                                        Integer.parseInt(tYear.getText()),tGender.getText());
            sLogic.addStudentArray(temp); // this is line 168
```

addStud.dispose();
    }

this is the contsructor where sLogic is declared

```
 public StudentGUI() throws Exception{
    ButtonHandler bh = new ButtonHandler();
    //Instantiate Main frame buttons
    add = new JButton("Add Student");
    add.addActionListener(bh);
    del = new JButton("Delete Student");
    edit = new JButton("Edit Student");
    edit.addActionListener(bh);
    save = new JButton("Save Changes");
    //Main frame buttons added to JPanel actions
    actions = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints b = new GridBagConstraints();
    b.insets = new Insets(5,0,5,0);
    b.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    actions.add(add,b);
    b.gridy = 1;
    actions.add(del,b);
    b.gridy = 2;
    actions.add(edit,b);
    b.gridy = 3;
    actions.add(save,b);

    sLogic = new StudentLogic();
    model = new  DefaultTableModel(sLogic.getStudentArray(),sLogic.getColumnLabel());
    table = new JTable(model){
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row,int col){
            return false;
        }
    };
    //add Jtable to scroller
    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(table);

    main = new JFrame("Student Database");
    main.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints a = new GridBagConstraints();
    a.insets = new Insets(10,5,10,5);
    main.add(scroller,a);
    a.gridx=1;
    a.weighty = 1;
    main.add(actions,a);
    main.pack();
    main.setVisible(true);
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //set JButtons edit and del disabled as default
    edit.setEnabled(false);
    del.setEnabled(false);
}
```

and here is the method addStudentArray()

```
public void addStudentArray(Student studArr){
        studs =  Arrays.<Student>copyOf(studs,studs.length+1);
        studs[studs.length-1]=studArr;
    }
```

which is in a class with the constructor:

```
public StudentLogic() throws Exception {
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("students_updated.dat"));
    input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("students.dat"));
    studs = (Student[]) input.readObject();
    studs2 = new Object[studs.length][5];
    for(int i = 0; i < studs.length; i++){
        studs2[i][0]=studs[i].getID()+"";
        studs2[i][1]= studs[i].getName();
        studs2[i][2]= studs[i].getCourse();
        studs2[i][3]= studs[i].getYr();
        studs2[i][4]= studs[i].getGender();
    }
    input.close();
}
```

I am stuck with this exception and I can't figure out why it returns npe. I am quite sure I have declared. I can post more of the code if required. Thanks in advance :)

As for the console

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at StudentGUI$ButtonHandlerSub.actionPerformed(StudentGUI.java:168)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Line 168 is sLogic.addStudentArray(temp);

Comment: you should post the console output so everyone knows which line etc the exception occurs on

Comment: Which line throws you the NPE?

Comment: NPE is at line 168 which is sLogic.addStudentArray(temp);

Comment: which would imply that sLogic is null.

Comment: Perhaps `sLogic` is 'null'. Where do you initialize it?

Comment: Where is variable sLogic created? is it out of scope?

Comment: @Woody Well I did but I can can't figure out which turns out to be null. I did instantiate both arrays and even tried to use System.out.print() and it does have contents.

Comment: @radimpe it is in the constructor of where the buttonlistener was

Comment: Do you really need to use arrays on this? Because it will be better if you use `List<Student>` with `ArrayList<Student>` implementation. Also, from the actual code, we cannot read the line where `addStudentArray` method is being called (and throwing the exception).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the sLogic in your ButtonHandlerSub object, is different from the one in the StudentGUI, which is initialized.

This is what you wrote:

```
public StudentGUI() throws Exception{
    ButtonHandler bh = new ButtonHandler();
    ...
    sLogic = new StudentLogic();  // <- this is not the bh.sLogic!
    ...
```

Comment: I seem to get it now.. But if i instantiated it within the class as `private StudentLogic sLogic;` isn't it supposed to be accesible within the class?

Comment: I can't see the hierarchy now. Is the ButtonHandler class declared inside the StudentGUI? Does the ButtonHandler have a sLogic variable?

Comment: I transferred my if statement from the ButtonHandlerSub to the  ButtonHandler and it seemed to work fine now. Thanks sir!

Answer (score 0):

The following will prevent there being a null in `studs` for a moment.

```
public synchronized void addStudentArray(Student studArr){
    Student[] enlargedStuds = Arrays.copyOf(studs, studs.length + 1);
    enlargedStuds[enlargedStuds.length - 1] = studArr;
    studs = enlargedStuds;
}
```